# PHImagemanager requestImageForAsset memory issue

Tags: xcode

I want to use PHImagemanager to get all photos on the device.
If I set the targetsize too high the app will crash because of memory warnings. So I tested the request without any use of the returned images and set each image to nil, but still app is crashing. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help please?

```
requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
requestOptions.synchronous = false;
assetsOfPhotos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType: PHAssetMediaTypeImage options: nil];
PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
@autoreleasepool {
    for (int i = 0; i <= totalImages - 1; i++) {
        PHAsset *asset = assetsOfPhotos[i];
        [manager requestImageForAsset: asset
                           targetSize: CGSizeMake(640, 480)
                          contentMode: PHImageContentModeDefault
                              options: requestOptions
                        resultHandler: ^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
                            image = nil;
                        }];
    }
}
```

Setting size to 640x480 crash after about 200 images, 320x240 after about 800 images. As a 640x480 image needs 4 times memory then 320x240 image it seems that the app crashes after the same amount of memory that was allocated. So for me this means that I cannot show more images than 200 imags with 640x480 on the test device, because I cannot free allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your `@autoreleasepool` work you need to set `requestOptions.synchronous` to `YES`, and use your own async queue if you want to make the request operation asynchronously.

Answer (score -1):

Please use @autoreleasepool inside the for loop.

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= totalImages - 1; i++) {
     @autoreleasepool {

         //Your code

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want load all photos that you have in Photos.app and you didn't want iCloud. You can do:

That example works with a collection view.

```
@interface GalleryViewModel ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray<PHAsset *> *assets;
@property (strong, nonatomic) PHImageManager *imageManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray<UIImage *> *imagesList;

@end

@implementation GalleryViewModel

- (instancetype) initWithContext:(ITXAppContext *)context {
    self = [super initWithContext:context];
    if (self) {
        _assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _imageManager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
        _requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
        _imagesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Public methods

// ==================================================================================
// Public methods

- (void) viewModelDidLoad {
    [self obtainAllPhotos];
}

#pragma mark - Private methods

// ==================================================================================
// Private methods

- (void) obtainAllPhotos {

    self.requestOptions.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
    self.requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
    self.requestOptions.synchronous = YES;
    self.requestOptions.networkAccessAllowed = NO;

    PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
    PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];

    __weak GalleryViewModel *weakSelf = self;
    [result enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        [weakSelf.assets addObject:obj];
        if (idx >= ([result count] - 1)) {
            [weakSelf.viewDelegate setupView];
        }
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Get data from object

// ==================================================================================
// Get data from object

- (NSInteger) sizeGallery {

    if (self.assets) {
        return [self.assets count];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UIImage *) imagesFromList:(NSInteger) index {

    __block UIImage *imageBlock;

    [self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:[self.assets objectAtIndex:index] targetSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200) contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:self.requestOptions resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
        if (result) {
            imageBlock = result;
        }
    }];

    return imageBlock;
}

@end
```